# Input Type: Separating JavaScript Code From Front End Code

Tags: javascript

The following is code that is within an html file.  What is the ideal way to separate the JavaScript code (`if (this.value etc etc)`) from html file?

```
input type="text" name="username" onblur="if (this.value == '')  {this.value = 'email';}" onfocus="if (this.value == 'email') {this.value = '';}"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<head> 
    <script type="text/javascript">  
        function ClearDefValue (input) { 
            if (input.value == '')  {
                input.value = input.defaultValue;
            }
        } 
        function SetDefValue (input) { 
            if (input.value == input.defaultValue) {
                input.value = '';
            }
        } 
    </script> 
</head> 
<body> 
    <input type="text" name="username" value="email" onblur="ClearDefValue (this)" onfocus="SetDefValue (this)" /> 
</body>
```

If you want to put the JavaScript content into an external file:

HTML file:

```
<head> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="utils.js"></script>
</head> 
<body> 
    <input type="text" name="username" value="email" onblur="ClearDefValue (this)" onfocus="SetDefValue (this)" /> 
</body>
```

utils.js file:

```
function ClearDefValue (input) { 
        if (input.value == '')  {
            input.value = input.defaultValue;
        }
} 
function SetDefValue (input) { 
        if (input.value == input.defaultValue) {
            input.value = '';
        }
}
```

Related links:
[script element](http://help.dottoro.com/lhcmkwcx.php),
[onblur event](http://help.dottoro.com/ljjhfrjd.php),
[onfocus event](http://help.dottoro.com/ljlmvqok.php).

Answer (score 1):

```
<!doctype html>
<html><head>
<script src="file.js"></script></head><body>
<input id="foo" type="text">
</body></html>
```

**Method #1:**

in file.js which you reference in the `<head>` with a `<script>`:

```
window.onload = function() {
 var input = document.getElementById('foo');
 input.onfocus = function() { if ( this.value == '' ) { this.value = 'blah';} }
 input.onblur = function() { if ( this.value == 'blah') { this.value = ''; } }
}
```

And ideally you'd want to use an addEvent function which supports dom listeners.

**Method #2:**

The (arguably) more elegant way would be:

```
var addEvent = (function() {
function addEventIE(el, ev, fn) {
    return el.attachEvent('on' + ev, function(e) {
    return fn.call(el, e);
    });
}
function addEventW3C(el, ev, fn) {
    return el.addEventListener(ev, fn, false);
}
return window.addEventListener ? addEventW3C:addEventIE;
})();

addEvent(window, 'load', function() {
    var input = document.getElementById('foo');
    addEvent(input, 'blur', function(){});
    addEvent(input, 'focus', function(){});

});
```

**Method #3:**

You can also avoid the whole `onload` and `addEvent` nonsense and just put your script before the end body tag if it's a fairly simplistic site.

```
<script src="file.js"></script>
</body>
```

file.js:

```
 var input = document.getElementById('foo');
 input.onfocus = function() { if ( this.value == '' ) { this.value = 'blah';} }
 input.onblur = function() { if ( this.value == 'blah') { this.value = ''; } }
```

Comment: For method 1, what would it look like if you had two fields?

Comment: `document.getElementsByTagName('input')` and a for loop. Should've told me about it first :(

Comment: Will this work:
window.onload = function() {
 var input = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
 
 for(var k = 0; k < input.length; k++)
 {
  var inputs = input[k];
  if(inputs.id = 'userName')
  {
   inputs.onfocus = function() { if ( this.value == 'email' ) { this.value = '';} }  
   inputs.onblur = function() { if ( this.value == '') { this.value = 'email'; } }
  }
  else if(inputs.id = 'passWord')
  {
   inputs.onfocus = function() { if ( this.value == 'password' ) { this.value = '';} }
    inputs.onblur = function() { if ( this.value == '') { this.value = 'password'; } }   
  }
 }
}

Comment: Just figured it out, sorry about the messy code.  Thanks again meder. Great help.